# Loop multiple qplot in same graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

Im struggling with producing multiple graphs in one frame with ggplot2. My problem is that I want to use a loop to select each graph separately and then plot it inside the frame. The problem is that qplot use the same data for each graph, while it changes the title of the graphs.

Here´s my code:

```
require("ggplot2")
require("gridExtra")

columns <- 1:4

#myData is a data.frame and looks like:
head(myData)[1:4]
  Crude Oil Heating Oil Natural Gas Cocoa
1     18.54        0.57        2.15  1278
2     17.40        0.50        2.18  1415
3     17.07        0.49        2.08  1221
4     20.69        0.57        2.14  1248

for (i in 1:length(columns)) {

p <- (qplot(data=myData, x=time, geom="blank")
+ geom_line(aes(y=myData[[i]]))
+ labs(title=names(myData[i]), y=NULL, x=NULL)
+ theme_bw())
plots[i] <- list(p)

}

args.list <- c(plots,list(nrow=2,ncol=2))
do.call(grid.arrange, args.list)
```

Due to my lack of reputation, I'm not able to upload the output here so I have to use tinypic instead:
http://sv.tinypic.com/r/zu38tv/8

Comment: What is in `myData`? Is it a list of data frames or of vectors? In any case, it would be a good idea to use `facet_wrap` for this (that is, to combine `myData` into a single data frame with a `Type` column, then do `qplot(...) facet_wrap(~ Type)`)

Comment: Sorry, myData is a list of data frames

Comment: And what does each of them look like: can you post `head(myData[[1]])`?

Comment: Something is fishy here: myData doesn't look like it's a list of data frames, it looks like it's a single data frame. Could you edit into your question (use the `edit` link) the results of `dput(head(myData))`?

Comment: Sorry, its a single data.frame. Ive updated the original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easier to use "long" data rather than "wide" data with ggplot2 ([see here](http://www.r-bloggers.com/reshape-package-in-r-long-data-format-to-wide-back-to-long-again/)). This means the first thing to do is get your data into the right format:

```
library(reshape2)
myData$Time = time
data.melted = melt(myData, id="Time")
```

This turns it into a format more like:

```
Time   variable   value
1      Crude Oil  18.54
2      Crude Oil  17.40
```

At that point, it's easy to make this kind of plot with facetting (no for loop necessary):

```
print(ggplot(data.melted, aes(x=time, y=value)) + geom_line() + facet_wrap(~ variable)
           + theme_bw())
```

Comment: Thanks! That almost solved my problem. Its just that the scale on the y-axis differs a lot in my data and this code uses the same scale for each graph. Edit: used `scales="free"` and works fine now. Thanks!